# Best versions of ubuntu for thinkpad T21

Tags: thinkpad

Anybody have any experiences about installing Ubuntu onto a Thinkpad T21? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That laptop is very old, so most drivers should work out of the box. However since the max RAM is 512 MB and it is a Pentium III, you'll be better off with Lubuntu, Puppy Linux or SliTaz Linux.

Check the following links for more info.

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_on_a_ThinkPad_T21

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-lightweight-linux-distributions-give-pc-lease-life

Comment: I bought a Thinkpad T61 for 200 dollars on eBay, everything runs fine. You may wanna get a 'new' old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is Elementary OS with the lightweight Pantheon DE, very light yet eye candy, itself based on 12.04 LTS for compatibility & supported to the latter third of 2017. Whatever your distro, the T21's graphics will not render modern video, consider upgrading the whole laptop.

https://askubuntu.com/a/227156/6735