# Lubuntu 12.04 on an IBM ThinkPad T21

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

Fairly new to linux in general, I've tried it multiple times in the past but never really stuck.  I've had a T21 for ages and decided to use it when I'm not in the mood to sit at my desktop on the couch.

Anyway I've installed lubuntu 12.04 on it and have been happy with the operating system for all but one reason... I can't do anything about the poor video performance.  Now I realize that a Savage S3 MX/IX with only 8mb won't ever be anything special.  I've done some googleing and found a few things, such as Xorg server no longer supports this card (correct me if i'm wrong please) as it did in a 2.6.x kernel based os.  glxgears gets all of 3-5 fps.  240p youtube videos absolutely kills it where as in xp which i dont want to go back to could handle it fairly smoothly.

There is no additional drivers in jockey.  I've downloaded a dri savage s3 driver but fails to install because it requires a 2.6 kernel.. I've searched synaptic for a 2.6 kernel to no avail.

If anyone would have any suggestions for me to try it would be greatly appreciated.

-xrs

Answer (score 4):

For T21 you must use an older version of mesalib. Version 8 killed 3d support for old video cards like T21's savage. Lubuntu 11.10 (with mesalib 7.11) is the last Lubuntu with full support for your video card out of the box. Using a distribution with a newer version of mesalib you must downgrad mesalib.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do. Your system is rather old and it would be better to use a stripped down window manager like plain Openbox (you can choose this from your login screen) or just replace the system.